# Can I use array reference at setOnClickListener(new OnClick(){});

Tags: java, android

I was coding an android application, and I ended the second activity.

```
public class OneBoardActivity extends Activity {
    //omitted
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_board);

    turn=true;
    statetext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.StateText);
    mover[0][2]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mover13);
    mover[0][3]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mover14);
    mover[0][4]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mover15);
            //omitted again
            for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(j=0;j<7;j++){
            if(i<=1 && j<=1 || i>=6 && j<=1 ||
                    i<=1 && j>=6 || i>=6 && j>=6){
                moverState[i][j]=-2;
                continue;
        }
        mover[i][j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ //Line 92
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Move by State
            moveByState(i,j);
        }
    });
    //omitted for the last time
```

...and this code ended without any syntax errors.
BUT, when I ran this application and got this activity out, this application resulted a "Unfortunately, ..." error.

This is the logcat:

```
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): Process: com.truefalseapps.solitaire, PID: 1230
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.truefalseapps.solitaire/com.truefalseapps.solitaire.OneBoardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.truefalseapps.solitaire.OneBoardActivity.onCreate(OneBoardActivity.java:92)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-16 04:09:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     ... 11 more
```

Does it mean I can't use an array reference at `setOnClickListener(new OnClick(){});` ?
If I can, then where does this NPE come from?

Comment: `mover[i][j]` is null

Comment: If you put your Buttons (or whatever) on the array `mover`, you can use this approach. But now the `mover` array is null like the above commentator said.

Comment: How is mover declared ?

Comment: @BatuhanC I editted the question. I have used findViewById(id) to put the buttons in the array.

Comment: @ToYonos I just typed up `Button mover[][] = new Button[7][7];` under `public class OneBoardActivity extends Activity`

Comment: But your nested loop has `i<7` and `j<7`. There is no Button on `mover[0][5]` or `mover[1][5]` or...

Comment: @BatuhanC That was exactly the problem I was having. I found it after catching something fishy in ToYonos' answer below - sorry. I didn't refresh the copter, so I got to see his answer faster than your comment.

Comment: @MetaData Good to hear that you solved your problem.

Comment: @BatuhanC Thanks... But now I've got another exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are many cases where mover[i][j] is null

```
Button mover[][] = new Button[7][7];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<7;j++)
    {
        if(i<=1 && j<=1 || i>=6 && j<=1 || i<=1 && j>=6 || i>=6 && j>=6)
        {
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println("Setting mover["+i+"]["+j+"]");      
    }
}
```

It's giving

```
Setting mover[0][2]
Setting mover[0][3]
Setting mover[0][4]
Setting mover[0][5]
Setting mover[1][2]
Setting mover[1][3]
Setting mover[1][4]
Setting mover[1][5]
Setting mover[2][0]
Setting mover[2][1]
Setting mover[2][2]
Setting mover[2][3]
Setting mover[2][4]
Setting mover[2][5]
Setting mover[2][6]
Setting mover[3][0]
Setting mover[3][1]
Setting mover[3][2]
Setting mover[3][3]
Setting mover[3][4]
Setting mover[3][5]
Setting mover[3][6]
Setting mover[4][0]
Setting mover[4][1]
Setting mover[4][2]
Setting mover[4][3]
Setting mover[4][4]
Setting mover[4][5]
Setting mover[4][6]
Setting mover[5][0]
Setting mover[5][1]
Setting mover[5][2]
Setting mover[5][3]
Setting mover[5][4]
Setting mover[5][5]
Setting mover[5][6]
Setting mover[6][2]
Setting mover[6][3]
Setting mover[6][4]
Setting mover[6][5]
```

However, you are just setting these 3

```
mover[0][2]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mover13);
mover[0][3]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mover14);
mover[0][4]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mover15);
```

When `mover[0][5]` happens, it throws a NullPointerException

Comment: Please note that I've omitted some codes. I've setted every buttons you showed me, but I omitted bcause it would've been so long... wait, hold on a minute.

Comment: So maybe a findViewById returns null and one of your button is null so. Without a full code, hard to help you

Comment: WOW... Thanks for helping me find my error. I've found something fishy, even though that isn't the problem you think. Thanks anyway!